# When trying to debug getting a nginx 502 with php 7.0.1 and Xdebug 2.4.0RC4-dev

Tags: php, nginx, xdebug, puphpet

Whenever I try to start debugging anything I get a 502 Bad Gatetway.

How can I find out whats wrong?

```
PHP 7.0.1-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.4.0RC4-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log

```
[21-Dec-2015 04:12:16] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[21-Dec-2015 04:12:16] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1460
[21-Dec-2015 04:12:16] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[21-Dec-2015 04:12:16] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[21-Dec-2015 04:17:23] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[21-Dec-2015 04:17:23] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[21-Dec-2015 04:17:23] ALERT: [pool www] pm.max_children must be a positive value
[21-Dec-2015 04:17:23] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[21-Dec-2015 04:17:23] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[21-Dec-2015 04:18:19] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 6941
[21-Dec-2015 04:18:19] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[21-Dec-2015 04:18:19] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[21-Dec-2015 04:19:03] WARNING: [pool www] child 6945 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 43.874016 seconds from start
[21-Dec-2015 04:19:03] NOTICE: [pool www] child 6975 started
```

All other logs are clear. What can I do? How can I find out whats wrong?
It's a puphpet.com machine.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm seeing Jan 12 02:19:47 vagrant-ubuntu-wily-64 kernel: [ 9067.322659] php-fpm7.0[16660]: segfault at 11 ip 00007f91ebbb7082 sp 00007ffdaf8d80c0 error 4 in xdebug.so[7f91ebb8e000+38000]

Comment: Hi Steve, sadly I couldn't find a solution or the cause :(

Comment: Thanks. I gave up too after fighting it for 3 days. Got a hunch its a problem with xdebug in php7

Answer (score 1):

This is an Xdebug bug. Usually I try to lock libraries to a specific version, but since Xdebug is a developer's tool, and because PHP7 just came out, I switched it to follow master.

If you're seeing issues with your version, I recommend cloning the repo, checking out a tag, and compiling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's because of the PHP throws OOM error. The xdebug default config

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 15
```

at the same time if you set

```
    xdebug.collect_vars = 1
    xdebug.collect_return = 1
    xdebug.collect_params = 1
    xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
    xdebug.dump_undefined = 1
    and so one
```

these options take too much memory. So try to change like

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3
```

(one small number) or close those options who takes so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 and Xdebug v2.4.0.
I think your version of xdebug is not stable. I have solved this issue by upgrading the version of Xdebug.

I suggest you to install a recent version of Xdebug, with pecl, not with apt.

```
sudo apt-get remove php-xdebug
sudo apt install php-pear php-dev
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

My current version of Xdebug is v2.5.5, and the issue has disappeared

https://xdebug.org/docs/install